# Should I write in the destructor call to all it's fields' destructors in Delphi?

Tags: class, oop, delphi, constructor, pascal

```
TB = Class;
TC = Class;
TA = Class
  Strict Private
      B : TB;
      C : TC;

  Public
      Constructor Create;
      Destructor  Destroy; Override;
      //something
End;

//something 

Constructor TA.Create;
B := TB.Create;
C := TC.Create;
End;

Destructor TA.Destroy;
B.Free;//needed?
C.Free;//needed?
End;
```

Is it needed to call to Free all the fields in the class' destructor, or it's not needed but it's a good style to be verbose?

Comment: Yes.  Wherever you create something, you must also destroy it.  The alternative is a memory leak.  These objects don't *need* to be freed in the destructor, and don't *need* to be created in the constructor (although they can be) - this is a matter of architecture and design.  Regardless, if you create an object you must destroy it.

Comment: @J... just in some languages they would be destroyed automatically along with the object of class that posses them

Comment: With that said, for classes that are only created once and persist for the lifetime of the application you can *get away* with not freeing member object fields that themselves are also only ever created once and persist for the lifetime of the application, and while it technically produces a memory leak, it isn't one that will bother you.  It's a common enough edge case that it can encourage one to be sloppy, so don't - just destroy things you create and be done with it.

Comment: yes, but you are not asking about "some languages" - you're asking about Delphi.  The above is correct for Delphi.

Comment: What @J... said is correct for the situation you asked about (basic classes). However, if you base (inherit) your classes on `TComponent` then you can write your code so that you assign an owner, which then becomes responsible for destruction. That is how e.g. forms will clean up all of their child components.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Sure, and other cases exist also - creating an object that implements an interface and storing it in an interface variable removes the need to explicitly free the object, as does using structures like `TObjectDictionary<T>` which also implement an ownership hierarchy.

Comment: I guess the point is that object lifetime is always something you need to be thinking about, and just because there are cases where you don't have to do it explicitly yourself in code, you still have to explicitly consider the lifetime of all objects and ensure that they will be freed appropriately, whether that's explicitly by you the developer, or automatically in certain cases.  It's never fully automatic, so we can never ignore it when we are designing new code.

Comment: It is also important to call inherited in your destructor. If you don't do that ancestor destructor will not be called and this can also create memory leaks or other issues if that destructor implements some code. If your ancestor is plain class then ancestor destructor does nothing, but it is still customary to call inherited - this is where being verbose and consistent helps in avoiding issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example code you give, you indeed MUST destroy the objects your created. This is the general rule.

If your objects inherit from `TComponent`, and when you call the `constructor` passing an owner, then that owner is responsible for destroying the component. But you can - if you like - also free it in your `destructor`.

If your objects are created because they are assigned to a variable of type `interface` (That is implemented by the object), then you should NOT destroy (free) it. This is because interfaces are reference counted and the object if freed automatically when there is no more reference to it. Of course the object must correctly implement that reference counting (`TInterfacedObject` is a base class you can use as ancestor if you don't want to bother with reference counting. But that is another story).